# What does it mean by one Dirac measure and two Dirac measure

Tags: definition, dirac-delta

Recently, I read paper where they write "assume that $\mu_1$ is defined by one Dirac measure and $\mu_2$ is defined by two Dirac measure".  I did not understand this point. What does exactly mean by "defined by one Dirac measure and two Dirac measure". I understand Dirac measure as indicator function over a set.

Comment: The context might provide a clue. Would "assume that $\mu_1$ is defined by one Dirac measure and $\mu_2$ is defined by a second Dirac measure" make sense in the context?

Comment: I agree with Andreas Blass. Most likely the author of the paper was not fluent in English and mistranslated what should have been "first" and "second" as "one" and "two".